# C# DateTimePicker Make a Reservation 2 days from today

Tags: c#, sql

I have my reservation system, i almost complete it but the problem is that panelists wants us to restrict the user to reserve this day, the current day which i've done to do so. But they've changed their mind, they want the user to reserve 2 days after this day. If the date today is Feb. 7 2019(which is in the datetimepicker) the user can only make a reservation 2 days from today. Means, the user must change the datetimepicker to Feb. 9 2019 to make a reservation.

Ive crawled , surfed from the internet from the past 3 days and i cant find any solution.

Comment: Can you show us your code? Because it's a bit hard to guess what you have done already...

Comment: ar you using Windows Forms, Asp.Net, WPF ?

Comment: What part are you having a problem with, and what have you tried so far? The logic seems simple enough, something like `if (selectedDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)) { ... }` might be a step in the right direction, for instance

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do? Do you only want to select Feb. 9 2019 instead of Feb. 7 2019?

Comment: Also, you've tagged `sql` - which layer are you planning to do this validation in?

Comment: im using winforms , sorry forgot to tell.

Answer (score 0):

For windows forms:

DateTimePicker has a MaxDate property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate?view=netframework-4.7.2

At the time your form is shown, set the Maxdate to a date two days into the future:

```
myDatePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
```

This will restrict the user to only being able to choose dates up to two days into the future, but not any further into the future than 2 days

If you meant to have it that the user can only choose dates two days or more into the future, use the MinDate property instead